# Hamming distance between two strings in Python

Tags: python, string, xor

I need to find the Hamming distance between two strings:

```
chaine1 = 6fb17381822a6ca9b02153d031d5d3da

chaine2 = a242eace2c57f7a16e8e872ed2f2287d
```

The XOR function didn't work, and my search on the web was not very successful.

I tried to modify something I found on the web, but there's some invalid syntax...:

```
assert len (chaine1) == len(chaine2)

return sum(chaine1 != chaine2 for chaine1, chaine2 in zip(chaine1, chaine2))


if __name__=="__main__":
chaine1 = hashlib.md5("chaine1".encode()).hexdigest()

chaine2 = hashlib.md5("chaine2".encode()).hexdigest()
print hamming_distance(chaine1, chaine2)
```

How could I proceed?

Comment: What have you tried? Read [ask]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: Some references: *[hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)*, *[hexdigest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest)*, and [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Comment: Presumably, "`def hamming_distance(chaine1, chaine2):`" is missing from the beginning of the code, and the actual code was properly indented (not as posted here). But the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following is a program calculating the Hamming distance using two different ways.

```
import hashlib

def hamming_distance(chaine1, chaine2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(chaine1, chaine2))

def hamming_distance2(chaine1, chaine2):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x : ord(x[0])^ord(x[1]), zip(chaine1, chaine2))))

if __name__=="__main__":    
    chaine1 = hashlib.md5("chaine1".encode()).hexdigest()
    chaine2 = hashlib.md5("chaine2".encode()).hexdigest()
    
    #chaine1 = "6fb17381822a6ca9b02153d031d5d3da"
    #chaine2 = "a242eace2c57f7a16e8e872ed2f2287d"
    
    assert len(chaine1) == len(chaine2)
    
    print(hamming_distance(chaine1, chaine2))
    
    print(hamming_distance2(chaine1, chaine2))
```

The reason why you get `Invalid syntax: ...` is probably you don't have any indentations, which are required in Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

DNA1 = list("GAGCCTACTAACGGGAT")
DNA2 = list("CATCGTAATGACGGCCT") 

d = round(distance.hamming(DNA1, DNA2) * len(DNA1))
print(d)  # 7
```

Answer (score 0):

First we should review the definition of the Hamming distance between two strings:

> The Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number of positions at which these strings vary. In more technical terms, it is a measure of the minimum number of changes required to turn one string into another.

Let's get a solution for it.

```
def hamming(s1,s2):
result=0
if len(s1)!=len(s2):
    print("String are not equal")
else:
    for x,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(s1,s2)):
        if i!=j:
            print(f'char not math{i,j}in {x}')
            result+=1
return result
s1="rover"
s2="river"
print(hamming(s1,s2))
```

> **Result: char not match ('o', 'i') in 1**

Comment: This is ***also*** badly indented. Where did you copy it from? Code is often poorly rendered in blog posts (even if the source is correct).