# Pass Regex if string matches at least x% of expression

Tags: regex

I'm not sure whether this is possible with simple Regex, but suppose I want to see whether a string matches 80% of an expression.

Suppose the expression is:
`abcde`

and I want strings that match 80% of this expression to count as matches. For example:
`"abcdd"` passes (4/5 characters match)
"`abbde"` passes (4/5 characters match)
`"abbbe"` fails (3/5 characters match)

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't have exactly what you want only using regex, what language is your script ? Many languages have already functions doing what you want, example with PHP there is **similar_text()**, you can also check for **levenshtein()** for Python/PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expressions might have variable width, you cannot even define what "matches at least x% of expression" means.
However you can define a simple string pattern and calculate the [Hamming-Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172831/hamming-distance-between-two-strings-in-python) of your pattern to any given string.